# REST vs SOAP evolvability

Tags: rest, soap, rpc

I get the benefits of changing link uris, but that's really not what this question is about.

What I mean by evolvability is adding new features to a service or modifying (when possible) existing ones and that's actually it.

SOAP isn't that bad as REST community tends to talk about it when it comes to evolvability. For example:

1. In REST we can add new rel - in SOAP we can add new method. Both
   types of old clients will continue working with new services.
2. In REST we can add new form field and set its default value - in
   SOAP we could have service arguments as some ServiceArgs class and
   add a new field to ServiceArgs. That's ugly, but it works.

What are the evolvability examples when SOAP clients break and you can do nothing about it, while REST clients are handling the situation gracefully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SOAP is a **contract-based** technology. The entire client/server interaction is written up and codified in a big document (the `WSDL`) and must be agreed upon and honored by both sides in order for things to work. If either side decides to add features, the other side must "evolve" in lock-step with it. Both sides are completely coupled, joined at the hip, glued together, married, for ever.

The typical approach to enhancing your SOAP services is to create new WSDL documents for the new versions of the service, while also maintaining the older ones. Another technique is to create a new interface to contain new methods and inherit from the old one. The approach you describe in #1 is IMO  breaking the SOAP rules, because the client and server will now be using different contracts and it only works because **additive** changes (like new methods) can be shoe-horned in and most of the time things will work. The moment someone makes a **destructive** change then the client's contract will not match the server's and it's game over. It's a difficult process to manage, which is why most organizations opt to create entirely new WSDL for each new version of the API.

REST doesn't magically make all of these problems go away, but it makes things easier to manage **by not forcing you to bundle your entire distributed system's "contract" into one artifact**. You're using HTTP? Great, then you get to use all of the wonderful HTTP features that the web uses too: proxy servers, URLs, content negotiation, authentication, etc. You want to communicate using JSON encoding as well as XML? Knock yourself out. It's trivial to do in REST at any time, without affecting existing clients. You want security? Fine, start challenging for authenticated credentials using HTTP's in-built support for exactly that. All of these things (HTTP, JSON, etc) are standardized and described in different places and that's exactly how it should be.

SOAP combines the transmission protocol, location information, payload description, encoding choice and RPC methods into one ginormous document. If you want to make any change to anything in that list, you need a new document. Worse still, some of those things can't be changed at all.

REST separates those things out so that the pieces **can evolve independently**. Your URLs (or "URIs", to be more precise) are returned at runtime and assuming the client [doesn't start to hardcode them](http://morethancoding.com/2011/09/07/uri-construction-give-it-a-rest/) are evolvable without any changes needed to the client. Additive changes to your media types are trivial if your documentation makes it clear that new fields may appear in the future. You've also got the option of versioning your media types, allowing the co-existence of v1/v2/v3... media types within your system, and the client can pick (using the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers in HTTP) which one they want to use.

Ever heard the joke about the Porsche owner who buys a brand new car whenever the ashtray gets full? That's SOAP. What should be a trivial change requires a major overhaul. REST gives you the vacuum cleaner. You don't have to use it, but it sure is cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer.
Clearly SOAP services are less evolvable than RESTful ones are. However SOAP does allow for some degree of evolvability. You cannot change the format and some other things, but you can add methods and arguments (with a little trick described above). As you say, that will violate SOAP rules, but does it matter? It works.

Also you say when someone makes a destructive change to a SOAP service it's game over. It holds true for RESTful services as well. If you make a destructive change to a media type and a client cannot find a link it expects it's kaput as well.

Comment: Re: adding methods to SOAP interfaces (the "trick"): yes, it works but it works because of luck, not by design. It's essentially an unsupported technique. With REST, your architecture can evolve because evolution is core to REST, not prohibited at a basic level as it is with SOAP. Re: destructive changes - correct on both accounts. It's not something any programmatic client can deal with magically.