# Versioning REST API

Tags: rest

After having read a lot of material on REST versioning, I am thinking of versioning the calls instead of the API. For example:

```
http://api.mydomain.com/callfoo/v2.0/param1/param2/param3
http://api.mydomain.com/verifyfoo/v1.0/param1/param2
```

instead of first having

```
http://api.mydomain.com/v1.0/callfoo/param1/param2
http://api.mydomain.com/v1.0/verifyfoo/param1/param2
```

then going to

```
http://api.mydomain.com/v2.0/callfoo/param1/param2/param3
http://api.mydomain.com/v2.0/verifyfoo/param1/param2
```

The advantage I see are:

- When the calls change, I do not have to rewrite my entire client - only the parts that are affected by the changed calls.
- Those parts of the client that work can continue as is (we have a lot of testing hours invested to ensure both the client and the server sides are stable.)
- I can use permanent or non-permanent redirects for calls that have changed.
- Backward compatibility would be a breeze as I can leave older call versions as is.

Am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WXYw4J4QOU
I think URL versioning is the best approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Require an HTTP header.

`Version: 1`

The [Version](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Object_Headers.html#z13) header is provisionally registered in [RFC 4229](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4229#section-2.2.17) and there some legitimate reasons to avoid using an X- prefix or a usage-specific URI. A more typical header was proposed by **yfeldblum** at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2028664:

`X-API-Version: 1`

In either case, if the header is missing or doesn't match what the server can deliver, send a **412 Precondition Failed** response code along with the reason for the failure. This requires clients to specify the version they support every single time but enforces consistent responses between client and server. (Optionally supporting a `?version=` query parameter would give clients an extra bit of flexibility.)

This approach is simple, easy to implement and standards-compliant.

### Alternatives

I'm aware that some very smart, well-intentioned people have suggested URL versioning and content negotiation. Both have significant problems in certain cases and in the form that they're usually proposed.

#### URL Versioning

Endpoint/service URL versioning works if you control all servers and clients. Otherwise, you'll need to handle newer clients falling back to older servers, which you'll end up doing with custom HTTP headers because system administrators of server software deployed on heterogeneous servers outside of your control can do all sorts of things to screw up the URLs you think will be easy to parse if you use something like **302 Moved Temporarily**.

#### Content Negotiation

Content negotiation via the `Accept` header works if you are deeply concerned about following the HTTP standard but also want to ignore what the HTTP/1.1 standard documents actually say. The proposed MIME Type you tend to see is something of the form `application/vnd.example.v1+json`. There are a few problems:

1. There are cases where the vendor extensions are actually appropriate, of course, but slightly different communication behaviors between client and server doesn't really fit the definition of a new 'media type'. Also, [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1) reads, "*Media-type values are registered with the Internet Assigned Number Authority. The media type registration process is outlined in RFC 1590. Use of non-registered media types is discouraged."* I don't want to see a separate media type for every version of every software product that has a REST API.
2. Any subtype ranges (e.g., `application/*`) don't make sense. For REST APIs that return structured data to clients for processing and formatting, what good is accepting `*/*` ?
3. The `Accept` header takes some effort to parse correctly. There's both an implied and explicit precedence that should be followed to minimize the back-and-forth required to actually do content negotiation correctly. If you're concerned about implementing this standard correctly, this is important to get right.
4. [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) describes the behavior for any client that does not include an `Accept` header: *"If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types."* So, for clients you don't write yourself (where you have the least control), the most correct thing to do would be to respond to requests using the newest, most prone-to-breaking-old-versions version that the server knows about. In other words, you could have not implemented versioning at all and those clients would still be breaking in exactly the same way.

**Edited, 2014**:

I've read a lot of the other answers and everyone's thoughtful comments; I hope I can improve on this with the benefit of a couple of years of feedback:

1. [Don't use an 'X-' prefix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648). I think `Accept-Version` is probably more meaningful in 2014, and there are some valid concerns about the semantics of re-using `Version` raised in the comments. There's overlap with defined headers like `Content-Version` and the relative opaqueness of the URI for sure, and I try to be careful about confusing the two with variations on content negotiation, which the `Version` header effectively is. The third 'version' of the URL `https://example.com/api/212315c2-668d-11e4-80c7-20c9d048772b` is wholly different than the 'second', regardless of whether it contains data or a document.
2. Regarding what I said above about URL versioning (endpoints like `https://example.com/v1/users`, for instance) the converse probably holds more truth: if you control all servers and clients, URL/URI versioning is probably what you want. For a large-scale service that could publish a single service URL, I would go with a different endpoint for every version, [like most do](http://www.lexicalscope.com/blog/2012/03/12/how-are-rest-apis-versioned/). My particular take is heavily influenced by the fact that the implementation as described above is most commonly deployed on lots of different servers by lots of different organizations, and, perhaps most importantly, on servers I don't control. I always want a canonical service URL, and if a site is still running the v3 version of the API, I definitely don't want a request to `https://example.com/v4/` to come back with their web server's *404 Not Found* page (or even worse, *200 OK* that returns their homepage as 500k of HTML over cellular data back to an iPhone app.)
3. If you want very simple /client/ implementations (and wider adoption), it's very hard to argue that requiring a custom header in the HTTP request is as simple for client authors as `GET`-ting a vanilla URL. (Although authentication often requires your token or credentials to be passed in the headers, anyway. Using `Version` or `Accept-Version` as a secret handshake along with an *actual* secret handshake fits pretty well.)
4. Content negotiation using the `Accept` header is good for getting different MIME types for the same content (e.g., XML vs. JSON vs. Adobe PDF), but not defined for versions of those things (Dublin Core 1.1 vs. JSONP vs. PDF/A). If you want to support the `Accept` header because it's important to respect industry standards, then you won't want a made-up MIME Type interfering with the media type negotiation you might need to use in your requests. A bespoke API version header is guaranteed not to interfere with the heavily-used, oft-cited `Accept`, whereas conflating them into the same usage will just be confusing for both server and client. That said, namespacing what you expect into a named profile per 2013's [RFC6906](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6906) is preferable to a separate header for lots of reasons. This is pretty clever, and **I think people should seriously consider this approach**.
5. Adding a header for every request is one particular downside to working within a stateless protocol.
6. Malicious proxy servers can do almost anything to destroy HTTP requests and responses. [They shouldn't](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-ct-guidelines-20091006/#sec-altering-header-values), and while I don't talk about the [Cache-Control](http://odino.org/rest-better-http-cache/) or [Vary](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/07/11/header_versioning) headers in this context, all service creators should carefully consider how their content is consumed in lots of different environments.

Comment: Well written! I would love some more clarification on your four bullet points at the end. You say "this is important to get right", but what is right in this case?

Comment: If you were parsing the Accept header, you'd need to properly handle 1) ordering, 2) wildcards and 3) the 'quality factor', which changes the weighted values when calculating which kind of response to return. More at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Sounds like exactly what you should not do yourself, but use a library with that algorithm built in for.

Comment: @JoeLiversedge Thanks for the great answer, I really enjoyed reading your perspective on these different methods. I wonder if you could expand your answer to share your perspective on the profile-media-type method that Matthew shared in another answer.

Comment: As far as I understand from the link you provide from the w3, the Version header is intended to be used for versioning objects not resources, it says: ...When an editied object is resubmitted using PUT for example, this field gives the value of the Version . This typically allows a server to check for example that two concurrent modifications by different parties will not be lost... It seems to be a header for identifying changes in the data not in the structure, the idea behind api versioning is to to have backward compatibility on structure of your resources not about data history.

Answer (score 18):

This is a matter of opinion; here's mine, along with the motivation behind the opinion.

1. **include the version in the URL.**
   For those who say, it belongs in the HTTP header, I say: *maybe.* But putting in the URL is the accepted way to do it according to the early leaders in the field. (Google, yahoo, twitter, and more).  This is what developers expect and doing what developers expect, in other words acting in accordance with  the principle of least astonishment, is probably a good idea.  It absolutely does not make it "harder for clients to upgrade".  If the change in URL somehow represents an obstacle to the developer of a consuming application, as suggested in a different answer here, that developer needs to be fired.
2. **Skip the minor version**
   There are plenty of integers. You're not gonna run out. You don't need the decimal in there. Any change from 1.0 to 1.1 of your API shouldn't break existing clients anyway.  So just use the natural numbers.  If you like to use separation to imply larger changes, you can start at v100 and do v200 and so on, but even there I think [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) and it's overkill.
3. **Put the version leftmost in the URI**
   Presumably there are going to be multiple resources in your model. They all need to be versioned in synchrony.  You can't have people using v1 of resource X, and v2 of resource Y.  It's going to break something. If you try to support that it will create a maintenance nightmare as you add versions, and there's no value add for the developer anyway. So, `http://api.mydomain.com/v1/Resource/12345` , where `Resource` is the type of resource, and `12345` gets replaced by the resource id.

You didn't ask, but...

1. **Omit verbs from your URL path**
   REST is resource oriented. You have things like "CallFoo" in your URL path, which looks suspiciously like a verb, and unlike a noun. This is wrong. [*Use the Force, Luke.*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2we_B6hDrY)  Use the verbs that are part of REST:  GET PUT POST DELETE and so on.  If you want to get the verification on a resource, then do `GET http://domain/v1/Foo/12345/verification`.  If you want to update it, do `POST /v1/Foo/12345`.
2. **Put optional params as a query param or payload**
   The optional params should not be in the URL path (before the first question mark) unless you are suggesting that those optional params constitute a self-standing resource. So, `POST /v1/Foo/12345?action=partialUpdate&param1=123&param2=abc`.

Comment: Sorry am just seeing this...Good points "Omit verbs..." and "Put optional params...".

Comment: In your point number 3. I think it is more problematic to put versions leftmost in the uri, in REST you work with resources which map to entities. As the most of times multiple resources evolve separately for example a user having one new field which has nothing to do with a customer resource. In terms of implementation if you do it at the root level in the url then you need to be adding new mappings to all your resources even if they not changed. I think your concern is more at the level of algorithms using wrong version of entities but that has nothing to do with REST API versioning.

Comment: @raspacorp Is putting the version to the right something you have used in practice? Generally, from the API's I have looked at the version is to the left of the resource\entity identifier. I have a quandry right now because this is how I started my API's for a serverless set of services e.g `v1/resource/sub_resource`. I have now started to work on a second API only to find API gateway will not allow me to deploy a separate serverless project with `/v1` as the base path. Moving to the right would alleviate this issue, but it looks odd if there is no operation or sub resource. e.g `resource/v1`

Comment: @raspacorp Do you know of any public API's which use this versioning approach that I could take a look at?

Comment: @berimbolo I've seen it in private and commercial apis only in companies I worked for, but only in two levels of depth like: ...accounts/v1/orders/v1/items, I agree it looks odd without a sub-resource

Answer (score 4):

Don't do either of those things, because they push the version into the URI structure, and that's going to have downsides for your client applications. It will make it harder for them to upgrade to take advantage of new features in your application.

Instead, you should version your media types, not your URIs. This will give you maximum flexibility and evolutionary ability. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993467/rest-vs-soap-evolvability/8995061#8995061) I gave to another question.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning, some proxy and intermediary servers strip out headers (possibly including media-types.) This could be a huge problem. Or am I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: I can't imagine a proxy or intermediary server stripping out a standard Accept header.

Comment: I'm all for versioning the media types but this one got me thinking: How do you model a change in behavior in one of your POST calls? Isn't that an API change, too? (Picked that up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024600/rest-api-versioning-only-version-the-representation-not-the-resource-itself/2028664#2028664)

Comment: If your service can now accept both old and new media types, then the client's job is to set the `Content-Type` header describing the version of the media type it's sending. If the service can only accept the new type then it should return something like `415 - Unsupported Media Type` when a client POSTs it data in unsupported format.

Comment: If the change in URL somehow represents an obstacle to the developer of a consuming application, as suggested in the answer here, that developer needs to be fired. The `v1` in the URL is not a real obstacle to developers upgrading and "taking advantage of new features in your application."

Comment: Versioning should be isolated to the appropriate and existing technique of content negotiation, not to the most fundamental structure of a RESTful application (the URI). Doing otherwise makes you throw the baby out with the bathwater when making upgrades.

Comment: Versioning might relate not only to content, but to API structure and semantics.

Answer (score 3):

I like using the profile media type parameter:

```
application/json; profile="http://www.myapp.com/schema/entity/v1"
```

More Info:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6906

http://buzzword.org.uk/2009/draft-inkster-profile-parameter-00.html

Comment: How do RFC 6906 and this IETF Draft relate to each other? RFC 6906 seems to be the definite standard, but it doesn't say how to use `profile` in `Accept` or `Link` headers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you call versions in your API, if you call versions to different representations (xml, json, etc) of the entities then you should use the accept headers or a custom header. That is the way http is designed for working with representations. It is RESTful because if I call the same resource at the same time but requesting different representations, the returned entities will have exactly the same information and property structure but with different format, this kind of versioning is cosmetic.

In the other hand if you understand 'versions' as changes in entity structure, for example adding a field 'age' to the 'user' entity. Then you should approach this from a resource perspective which is in my opinion the RESTful approach. As described by Roy Fielding in his disseration ...a REST resource is a mapping from an identifier to a set of entities... Therefore makes sense that when changing the structure of an entity you need to have a proper resource that points to that version. This kind of versioning is structural.

I made a similar comment in: http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/11/09/versioning-restful-services/

When working with url versioning the version should come later and not earlier in the url:

```
GET/DELETE/PUT onlinemall.com/grocery-store/customer/v1/{id}
POST onlinemall.com/grocery-store/customer/v1
```

Another way of doing that in a cleaner way but which could be problematic when implementing:

```
GET/DELETE/PUT onlinemall.com/grocery-store/customer.v1/{id}
POST onlinemall.com/grocery-store/customer.v1
```

Doing it this way allows the client to request specifically the resource they want which maps to the entity they need. Without having to mess with headers and custom media types which is really problematic when implementing in a production environment.

Also having the url late in the url allows the clients to have more granularity when choosing specifically the resources they want, even at method level.

But the most important thing from a developer perspective, you don't need to maintain the whole mappings (paths) for every version to all the resources and methods. Which is very valuable when you have lot of sub-resources (embedded resources).

From an implementation perspective having it at the level of resource is really easy to implement, for example if using Jersey/JAX-RS:

```
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerResource {
    ...
    @GET
    @Path("/v{version}/{id}")
    public IDto getCustomer(@PathParam("version") String version, @PathParam("id") String id) {
         return locateVersion(version, customerService.findCustomer(id));
    }
    ...
    @POST
    @Path("/v1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public IDto insertCustomerV1(CustomerV1Dto customer) {
         return customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/v2")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public IDto insertCustomerV2(CustomerV2Dto customer) {
         return customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    }
...
}
```

IDto is just an interface for returning a polymorphic object, CustomerV1 and CustomerV2 implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does verisoning [in the url](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.apigee.com%2Fdetail%2Frestful_api_design_tips_for_versioning&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEdjV_8IoRvgzK-qLTUWWc0nN3neA).  I feel url versioning is cleaner and easier to maintain as well in the real world.

.Net makes it super easy to do versioning this way:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{version}/someCall/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage someCall(string version, int id))
```