# Versioning endpoints with Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, sinatra

What is the preferred method for versioning Sinatra end-points.

I have an end-point named `purchases`. For v 0.1, should that be...?

```
get '/0.1/purchases' do
end
```

The Sinatra [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Versioning) was not particularly helpful.

Comment: Versioning URLS is rather controversial. I don't think Sinatra provides anything out of the box to handle it, but you might want to read this question for ideas on how to (conceptually) go about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning

Comment: This isn't something that falls under a specification where the Sinatra folks could implement it; More often that not it falls into the laps of the developers who are creating the API, meaning you and your team and/or enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

I've kept this one bookmarked:

[Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning)

Another:

[Versioning REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742594/versioning-rest-api)

Or:

https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_tips_for_versioning

I think they have some free API book downloads that might prove helpful, too.

(And as the other commenter noted, this topic tends to generate lots of discussion.)