# WSDL for SOAP - What about REST?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, wsdl

Pretty new to `WCF`

I was browsing through various `WCF Terminologies` and seems stuck understanding this.

`WSDL` is used to describe the web service.

Currently, only `SOAP` based web services seems to have an associated `WSDL` while `REST` based services doesn't seem too.

Why?

Is it possible to generate `WSDL` for `REST` too?

Or are there any third party programs to do it ?

Comment: Why? Because WSDL is intimately tied to SOAP, you cannot really create a WSDL for a REST service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`WADL`](https://wadl.java.net/) is  equivalent to WSDL for RESTful services

Comment: Thank you. But, Why did `.net` framework doesn't support  any kind of operation like this by default?

Answer (score 1):

Since Microsoft .NET does not natively support WADL (WADL is WSDL for REST) providing a specific answer to your question is a bit difficult.  That said, if you are interested in discovering more about RESTful services and WADL, you may want to consider experimenting with the open-source **soapUI** web service test utility (http://www.soapui.org/), which provides support for WADL.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of codifying a RESTful API into a never-changing contract is antithetical to REST. Yes, WADL exists, but its purpose is to try and make REST more like SOAP, and with it destroy the primary benefit of REST: its [evolvability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993467/rest-vs-soap-evolvability/8995061#8995061).

If you feel like you want to use WADL, just use WSDL/SOAP instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `swagger.json` as definitions for REST services.

you can check their github page for more information.

https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag